# DELETE and NOT IN query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table structure:

### Users

- UserId (primary key)
- UserName

### SomeItems

- SomeId(FK to Users.UserId)
- SomeItemId (primary key)
- Name
- Other stuff...

### SomeOtherItems

- SomeId2 (FK to Users.UserId)
- SomeOtherItemId (primary key)
- Name
- Other stuff...

I want to delete records from Users table which do not exist in SomeItems and SomeOtherItems tables.

I can do this:

```
DELETE from Users
FROM Users u
WHERE u.UserId NOT IN
   (SELECT DISTINCT SomeId FROM SomeItems

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT SomeId2 FROM SomeOtherItems)
```

However, it is very slow. I assume it executes the UNION query for every record, doesn't it? Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: How many rows are there in those three tables?

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the IN for two joins, the simpler the query, the easier is to optimize for the engine.

```
DELETE from U
FROM Users U
     left join SomeItems S1 on S1.SomeId = U.UserId
     left join SomeOtherItems S2 on S2.SomeID2 = U.UserId
WHERE S1.SomeId is null and S2.SomeID2 is null
```

Checking that S1.SomeID is null means that U.UserId was not present on SomeItems. Same for SomeOtherItems.

Be sure that you have indexes for SomeId and SomeID2 on SomeItems and SomeOtherItems.

Comment: You don't need a join to use an index.

Comment: The engine can just as easily optimize alternate syntax, too.

Comment: @MarcGuillot thank you for the answer. Your query takes 30 sec to complete, in opposite to my 65 sec

Comment: No, I was not suggesting you delete your answer. I was just attempting to clarify that a join is not required to use an index, and that neither syntax is "easier" for the engine to optimize, which your answer suggests.

Comment: @MarcGuillot No, I don't have indexes on those specific columns, but do have on some others (which not even mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 5):

Applying distinct on two results and then unioning them (which applies yet a third distinct, all requiring sorts) is not the most efficient way to validate existence. How about:

```
DELETE u
  FROM dbo.Users AS u -- always use schema prefix!
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SomeItems WHERE SomeId = u.UserId
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SomeOtherItems WHERE SomeID2 = u.UserId
  );
```

Comment: . . . I think `OR` instead of `AND` with `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @Yogesh OR would be with EXISTS. Check the logic of the original query.

Comment: Ha, my answer was identical. +1 from me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you. However, my query and yours are equal performance wise, both taking about 60-65 sec to complete for my data.

Comment: @Evgeny We'll need to look at the execution plans to see what indexes are, are not, or could be used. The syntax isn't causing that speed, but it could be an inefficient query plan (or, if the left join ran in 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds, perhaps it is blocking, because that certainly shouldn't be twice as efficient).

Answer (score 2):

the simplest fix might just be to change UNION to UNION ALL

you'll see the effect of this by the removal of the stream aggregate component of the query plan.

after all you don't care if the list is duplicated